# ColdFusion 2016 Can't start service after lockdown guide

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am working on testing out the ColdFusion 2016 release on a Windows 2012 server.  I've followed through Pete Freitag's excellent lockdown guide and I get to page 31 to restart ColdFusion and test. When I try to start from Services I get:

```
Windows could not start the ColdFusion 2016 Application Server service on
Local Computer.

Error 5:  Access is Denied
```

When I run the start from an Administrator command prompt, it appears to start (I omitted all of the other output, but there didn't seem to be any errors)

```
Jun 15, 2016 14:51:56 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - Starting WebSocket...
Jun 15, 2016 14:51:57 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - ColdFusion started
Jun 15, 2016 14:51:57 PM Information [localhost-startStop-1] - ColdFusion: application services are now available
```

Once that is done I tried to test the Administrator but it wouldn't connect.

Short of trying to work my way backwards through the guide, step by step until I find what broke it, any tips on what might cause this specifically based on that guide?

Comment: have you looked through the logs? (not sure where they are for acf)

Comment: Events logs:  The ColdFusion 2016 Application Server service failed to start due to the following error: 
Access is denied. with an error number of 7000.

Comment: Interesting - if I give 'SYSTEM' read, read & execute and list to my CF install folder the service starts, but I get a 500 error when trying to bring up the administrator.

Comment: Two questions for more clarity.
1) Are you able to access CF Admin?
2) Are you able to access cfm pages?

Comment: @AnitKumar - thanks for the follow up.  I ended up starting over, but now have a different issue.  My CF Admin runs fine, but when I try to bring up any .cfm page I get a 404 not found.  My /jakarta mapping is correct, I've rerun the connector tool etc. and still get a 404.  This is setup on AWS as a developer edition.  I thought I could access it from one outside IP and be fine with developer, but is that not the case?

Comment: Are you accessing the CF Admin from internal built in server or via IIS? Also, where are your cfm files? Can you reacreate the connector and check the permission on wsconfig folder as well?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make sure that if you set up an account for ColdFusion to run as and set up your Windows services to use this account, that the account has appropriate rights in the directory where your .cfm is being referenced. (item 2.18 in the lock down guide)